# The Center of Mass for proton-proton collisions at the LHC

Tags: special-relativity, energy, particle-physics, kinematics, collision

If bunches of protons are being circulated in both directions of the LHC collider with each proton having an energy $E_p=7\ \mathrm{TeV}$, then using the following "Lorentz Invariant Quantity" expression, $s$, for a collider:

$$s=4E_p^2$$

I can then take the square root $s$ to get

$$\sqrt{s}=\sqrt{4\times7^2}\ \mathrm{TeV}=14\ \mathrm{TeV}$$

Which is the center of mass energy for [proton-proton collisions at the LHC](http://www.lhc-closer.es/1/3/4/0).

I found the expression, $s$ on the [top of page 5 of some Oxford university notes](http://www-pnp.physics.ox.ac.uk/%7Emjohn/B6.pdf). However, I don't really get where $s$ was derived from, so I am not sure why it has a different form for this type of proton-proton collision.

Comment: Different from *what*? In the LHC context, $s$ is just one of the three [Mandelstam variables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandelstam_variables), I see nothing unusual here.

Comment: @ACuriousMind different to a fixed target machine for one. Also, that proof does not lead to $4E_p^2$ can you elaborate on what you're talking about?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The definition of $s$ is the following:

$$ s=(p_1+p_2)^2,$$

where $p_1$ and $p_2$ are the 4-momenta of each colliding proton. For head on collision of particles with same energy and momentum (like in LHC) these explicitly read $p_1=(E_p,\vec{p})$ and $p_2=(E_p,-\vec{p})$. Plug this in the  definition:
\begin{eqnarray}
s &=& p_1^2 + p_2^2 +2p_1\cdot p_2\\
 &=&(E_p^2-|\vec{p}|^2) + (E_p^2-|\vec{p}|^2)+2 (E_p^2+|\vec{p}|^2)\\
&=& 4E_p^2
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: It could be shorter, although basically the same as what you've written. $p_1=(E_p, \vec{p})$, $p_2=(E_p,-\vec{p})$, $p_1 + p_2 = (2E_p, \vec{0})$ so $s = 4E_p$.